# Is there any way we can find boundaries of multiple images and crop them out individually?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, counter

Is there any way we can find boundaries of multiple images and crop them out individually. I am able to crop individual image when they can be cropped symmetrically in a rectangular box, but it becomes challenging when image to be cropped is asymmetric. In the image attached there are two images, i.e. "detail B" and "detail C". I just wanted to crop them out into two individual images. Can anyone advise how to get these images using Python?

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is quite simple:

1. Inverse binary threshold a grayscale version of your image, e.g. using Otsu's method. Since you have all-white background, this should be fine.
2. To "merge" all neighbouring parts, i.e. the "detail" itself, the lines, and captions, dilate the resulting mask from the thresholding.
3. Find all external contours, filter the largest ones, and then one after another: Draw the filled contour on a separate mask, and set up a linear combination of your original image, where the mask is white, and an all-white image, where the mask is black; crop the correct part by finding the bounding rectangle of the contour.

Here's some Python code using OpenCV and NumPy:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io      # Only needed for web grabbing images

# Read image from web
image = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq12v.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Inverse binary threshold grayscale version of image using Otsu's
thres = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Dilate to merge all neighbouring parts
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
thres = cv2.dilate(thres, kernel)

# Find external contours with respect to OpenCV version
cnts = cv2.findContours(thres, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate all contours...
area_thr = 10000
k = 0
for c in cnts:

    # Filter large contours
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > area_thr:

        k = k + 1

        # Get bounding rectangle of contour
        rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        x1 = rect[0]
        y1 = rect[1]
        x2 = x1 + rect[2]
        y2 = y1 + rect[3]

        # Generate filled contour mask
        mask = np.zeros((thres.shape[0], thres.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (1, 1, 1), cv2.FILLED)

        # Generate and save cropped image
        crop = 255 * np.ones((thres.shape[0], thres.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
        crop = (1 - mask) * crop + mask * image
        crop = crop[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        cv2.imwrite('crop' + str(k) + '.png', crop)
```

The initial mask after thresholding and dilating looks like this:

[image: Mask]

We see six parts, whereas the two "details" are significantly larger.

The two cropped "details" are:

[image: Crop #1]

[image: Crop #2]

Hope that helps!

```
------------------
System information
------------------
Python:  3.8.1
NumPy:   1.18.1
OpenCV:  4.1.2
------------------
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for the quick help and its really giving a very nice results to complicated images. Is it possible to get coordinates of the  individual images which has been cropped with respect to original image which contained multiple images. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ashish The `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are exactly that.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can be able to give the code.

Comment: @Ashish It's already in the code! Go to the line, where `x1`, etc. are assigned. After that part, you can do whatever you want with the information stored in `x1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks buddy , it got it. Cheers

Comment: Is it possible to get multiple coordinates instead of four coordinates fof rectangular block which we were getting after using boundingrect(). how can we get irregular coordinates (not rectangular) of the image which has been cropped with respect to original image.

Comment: @Ashish You'd use the contour directly then. In any case, that'd be another, new question for sure.